# Frontpage crashes once i login

Tags: frontend, magento2.4.2

I am using magento 2.4.2. My site is working in 2 stores. English and Greek. without any login in frontend, everything works fine. My problem is that when i login from Greek store my site crashes. i get error 500  most of the times. Some times it is displaying content broken. If i login with English store everything is ok. Can you please advise what maybe the cause?

Comment: have you checked through logs when you get 500 error, also check for console errors in browser when you see broken content. if any please post errors here to better understand the issue.

Comment: Hello. I get this error in console. (index):236 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at (index):236
(anonymous) @ (index):236

Comment: can you post the html source from your browser close to line no. 236, may be from line no. 220 to 250

Comment: To be honest, i deleted one customer group, i reindexed and site is ok now. i had reindex before also but it was not working. No idea how but now is ok. Thank you very much for trying to help though.